# Angular JS - Autosuggest not working on my editor - sublime

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js , I have added the reference tag as below in my js file, but my autosuggest feature is not working while writing the code which is used by doing a ctrl + space , Can anyone please assist.

full code

```
 /// <reference path="angular.min.js" />

//create a module, register everything in one line , using chaining. 

var myApp = angular
                  .module("myModule",[])
                  .controller("myController", function($scope){

                            var employee = {
                            firstName : "David",
                            lastName : "Hastings",
                            gender : "Male"
                        };

                        //$scope.message = "Angular JS Tutorial ";
                        $scope.employee = employee; 
                    });
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Which editor do you use?

Comment: You should better specify what do you expect your "autosuggest feature" to do, and in response to which action. Knowing the name of your editor should help, too...

Comment: actually it looks like a TypeScript reference and not a JavaScript one

Comment: my editor is sublime, when i do a ctrl and space i cant see any angular autosuggest list my editor.